# D3 -- Can't set text color via css class

Tags: css, d3.js

I am using d3.js to create a javascript chart, and am trying to separate my styling from behavior as much as possible. To do this, I am trying to apply CSS classes using the .attr('class','...') method rather than using the .style() method. For the most part everything works just fine. However, when I try to apply a CSS class to set the stroke and fill of some text elements, it just doesn't work. The part that has me confused is the fact that the same process of using .attr() to apply a css class worked fine for the bars of the graph, and that I have no issue styling the text how I want if I use the exact same attributes, but instead with the .style() method to set each individually. Even more bizarre, I can use the .attr() method to apply a transparency class via css without any issue. Is there something I am missing here?

These are the css classes in question:

```
    .black {
    fill: rgb(41,41,41);
    stroke: rgb(41,41,41);
 }

 .red {
    fill: rgb(238,77,77);
    stroke: rgb(238,77,77);
    color: rgb(238,77,77);
 }

 .blue {
    fill: rgb(76,179,230);
    stroke: rgb(76,179,230);
 }

 .white {
    fill: rgb(255,255,255);
    stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
 }
```

and this is the code that, for some reason doesn't work:

```
 var severityText = chart.selectAll(".severity")
        .data(array)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth / 2 - (5.0/8)*barNumberSize; })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return bubbleY(maxBubbleValue - d['severity']) - bubbleRadius / 2 - bubbleNumberSize*(1.0/4) })
        .style("font-size", bubbleNumberSize.toString() + "px")
        //this line isn't doing its job
        .attr('class','white')
        .attr('class','transparent')
        .text(function (d, i) { return d['severity'].toString() });
```

while this code does:

```
var severityText = chart.selectAll(".severity")
        .data(array)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth / 2 - (5.0/8)*barNumberSize; })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return bubbleY(maxBubbleValue - d['severity']) - bubbleRadius / 2 - bubbleNumberSize*(1.0/4) })
        .style("font-size", bubbleNumberSize.toString() + "px")
        //works fine when written in this format.....why?
        .style('fill',white)
        .style('stroke',white)
        .attr('class','transparent')
        .text(function (d, i) { return d['severity'].toString() });
```

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting the class "white" with "transparent" immediately after setting it.

Comment: I see my error--I tried to apply classes by chaining as opposed to listing them all in the same string together. Thank you! If you want to post it as a solution I can accept it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set multiple classes, use a single string that contains all of them instead of chaining the calls, which will overwrite it.

That is, instead of

```
.attr('class','white')
.attr('class','transparent')
```

do

```
.attr('class', 'white transparent')
```

Answer (score 21):

It's better to use classed

```
.classed('white', true);
```

or even

```
.classed('white transparent', true);
```

This saves a lot of book keeping what class was set/removed later on. Adding a data provided class name is more difficult. See ie http://bl.ocks.org/clemens-tolboom/7231676

Comment: The actual API reference is https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_classed

Comment: And another explanation of this is in http://jaketrent.com/post/d3-class-operations/